# VueJS 3: Page styles not loaded in child route

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vue-router

Basically I have this route config:

```
{
    path: '/settings',
    name: 'settings',
    component: AppLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
        { path: 'profile2', component: ProfileComponent },
    ]
},
```

When I navigate to: `https://locahost:8000/settings` styles are loaded correctly. Please see:

[image]

but when I navigate to: `https://locahost:8000/settings/profile` page styles are not loaded. Please see:

[image]

This is so weird. Did I miss something? I am using `vue-router`.

Comment: Your chances of getting an answer without a *runnable* [mcve] are really slim, since this seems to be related to CSS. We have no way of knowing how you're loading those CSS rules and why they don't apply on the child route. Consider exporting the project to codesandbox.io or similar and make sure the bug is replicated.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from what you've shared but you should check if the styles on your parent route are having scope attribute in styles tag. Ex.

```
<style scoped></style>
```